# CONVERT/CAST Function not working for date conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to convert date from string variable

```
DECLARE @start_date VARCHAR(max)
SET @start_date = '7/12/2020 9.00 AM'
CONVERT(DATETIME2, @start_date, 103)
```

**Output :**

> Conversion Failed when Converting Date and/or Time from Character
> String

Also tried

```
CAST(@start_date AS DATETIME2(3))
```

**Output :**

> Conversion Failed when Converting Date and/or Time from Character
> String

Need suggestion and resolution

Comment: Is that 7th of December or 12th of July?

Comment: @nick its 12 July

Comment: @Nick converting without a style parameter is a bad idea and will fail under different cultures.

Answer (score 2):

try the following:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME2, replace(@start_date, '.', ':'), 101) Converted
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=86d48e9f5a3f208f41f7a435d202b5c0)

Comment: That's 7th December, OPs date is 12th of July (see comments to the question).

Comment: @RaG then you can simply replace '.' with ':' and then convert to datetime2.